# AWS load balancing (ALB) based on query string

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, query-string

I have two servers behind an AWS ALB. The request sent to the ALB looks like:

The query is :

> http://URL?customer_id=xxx

where *xxx* specifies the server which client request should be distributed to.

I have already tried to configure the rule with the path "*xxx*" and it doesn't work since it is not a path. it is the query.

Does ALB support forward request by the query string?

Comment: Hi Anis! Just a thought which might help people in answering the question: Why use a load balancer, if the server is clear before using a rule? And:  Why don't you use a path instead of the query?

Comment: I would like to hide servers behind ALB. Then servers doesn’t have a public IP. The environment is more complicated than I described above so I want to avoid changing paths and prefer to use query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALB does not support query string based rules -- only path patterns and hostname literals.